# wordpress divi active responsive menu by default

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I'd like to have my responsive menu in wordpress/divi show up as active by default on page load rather than requiring the user to have to first click on the hamburger icon. Is there a setting for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work through use of the Divi Plugin for the Pro Responsive Menu. There was an option to open on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using jQuery to add the required class and style to your menu items on page load. Something like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.mobile_nav').addClass('opened');
    $('#mobile_menu).css('display','block');
});
```

Comment: Do you know which wordpress php file touches every page? I can give it a try. Was hoping not to edit php files that there may be a setting somewhere in the Wordpress menu options or the theme customization.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a php file but if so, you should be able to put it in footer.php. You can also install a Header and Footer Scripts type plugin that lets you add scripts to the header or footer.